# Why did Captain Atom obey these orders?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

In the Justice League Unlimited Season 2 Episode 9, *Question Authority*, we see that General Eiling tells Captain Atom is reactivated as part of the Air Force.

Next we see we see him, he protects

> Project Cadmus

Claiming that he's operating legally and properly. This leads to Captain Atom

> fighting Superman, no holds barred.

What I wasn't clear on was whether or not Captain Atom truly believed he was acting under just orders, or if he was under some sort of mind control from the same entity he was protecting.

I'm not sure if it's said with 100% certainty in the show, but since the events of the DCAU are often based on the comics, swapping out characters here and there, I would be okay with a comic-based interpretation of events.

Answer (score 2):

Captain Atom was acting under orders and his own interpretation of those orders in accord with his principles, there was no explicit mind control other than the standard training and indoctrination one would expect from a U.S. military soldier.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Absence of proof can fit for a situation where someone is asking whether such proof is present. In this case, there's no evidence for mind control and it's perfectly viable that he was simply following his lawful orders.